# La cadena de entrada no tiene formato correcto. C# - DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

Tengo una enorme duda acerca de esto, como mencione en mi anterior pregunta estoy trabajando en un proyecto de final de clase de C# y DevExpress.

Este es el error que me sale pero tanto en la base de datos como en el programa lo tengo como entero y solo en este formulario me da error.

[image: Este es el error que me salta]

[image: La base de datos, aunque no creo que el error este aquí]

Este es el formulario que estoy rellenando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo extraño es que uso lo mismo para el otro formulario que tiene llaves foráneas y en este formulario me sirvió bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El profesor nos dio un ejemplo al inicio del semestre donde el hacia el código pero con un formulario más pequeño, yo lo agarre y lo adapte a lo que necesitaba. Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cambia las imágenes por texto o tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Te invito a leer [ask] y [recomendaciones sobre evitar imágenes en las preguntas y / o respuestas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/ser%c3%ada-posible-a%c3%b1adir-al-art%c3%adculo-c%c3%b3mo-elaboro-una-buena-pregunta-indicacion/4433#4433)

Comment: Apostaría que tienes mal puesto el nombre "te_id", el cual debe ser del label que está al lado (izquierdo) del textbox y no del textbox en cuestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que se equivoco poniendo los nombres y ese te_id es en realidad el label en vez del textbox por eso le esta diciendo que no puede convertir a número el texto "Número de consulta:"

Comment: Ya veo, me voy a fijar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, que vergüenza haberme equivocado al cambiarle la en nombre.